# Getting specific value from multi node xml with xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, select, xslt

I got the following xml;

```
  <output>
    <EmployeeList>
      <Employee>
        <EmployeeInfo>
          <Id>253</Id>
          <CarrierType>Employee</CarrierType>
          <ArrivalDateTime>2021-04-20T15:10:20</ArrivalDateTime>
          <ReadOnly>false</ReadOnly>
          <Freefield>
            <DefinitionId>50012</DefinitionId>
            <Name>PersoonType</Name>
            <value>2</value>
          </Freefield>
          <Freefield>
            <DefinitionId>50014</DefinitionId>
            <Name>Roostercode</Name>
            <value>TST04</value>
          </Freefield>
          <Freefield>
            <DefinitionId>50006</DefinitionId>
            <Name>Kaart lay-out</Name>
            <value>02_Medewerker_MBO</value>
          </Freefield>
          <Freefield>
            <DefinitionId>50007</DefinitionId>
            <Name>LoXS Master</Name>
            <value>false</value>
          </Freefield>
          <LastName>Tester4</LastName>
          <FirstName>Test</FirstName>
          <Gender>Unknown</Gender>
          <Language>nl</Language>
          <Email>ttester4@work.nl</Email>
        </EmployeeInfo>
      </Employee>
    </EmployeeList>
  </output>
```

Notice the Freefield node.
I need the value from one specific Freefield node in which the DefinitionId=50014 or Name=Roostercode. From this Freefield node i need the value; in this case 'TST04'.

I tried several variants of below code to select the value and assign it to a variable (rcode). So far this always results in some kind of error.

```
<xsl:variable name="rcode" select="/output/EmployeeList/Employee/EmployeeInfo/Freefield/[@Name='Roostercode']/value/text()"/>
```

Any idea to get this specific value?

Maybe i can not get this value directly so even other approaches are welcome!

The solution needs to be in xslt 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your verbal description `DefinitionId=50014 or Name=Roostercode` nearly translates into XPath: `//Freefield[DefinitionId=50014 or Name='Roostercode']/value`.